# Very simple Django form that counts words

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make a very simple Django form that has two options (buttons) once you type something in the form: one deletes what it has been written, and the other one counts the words with a function I already have.

I have been trying to learn from tutorials, but all seem too complicated for what this is (which I think, quite easy).

This is my HTML in the `env` templates Python project.

```
<html>
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit" value="Count!" >
        <input type="submit" value="Reset!">
    </form>

</html>
```

This is my .py file:

```
from django import forms

class Formu(forms.Forms):
    nombre=forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    def count(self, request):
        # My function to count
        pass

    def reset(self, request):
        # Reset(?)
        pass
```

I do not really know how to associate the buttons. I think I am missing some conceptual knowledge, because I do not really know what path should I follow now to associate the buttons `count` and `reset` in the `Formu` methods `count` and `reset`.

Comment: Well, I am trying to do it with Django, that is why I am asking about it! I know js already! @Lemayzeur

Comment: anyway, you will need to do it with js in case you don't want to reload the page as simple you said. and you can't compute these values from `Form`, but in your `view`

Comment: @M.K This question is too broad to be answered here. You should read a Django tutorial first, try something and then post the specific issue you are having (if any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Form` is not a `view`. It's just making inputs inside your form.

I.e., basic `forms.Form` from Django documentation

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

is rendered to HTML like this:

```
<label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
<input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" maxlength="100" required />
```

That's all. What you need is `View`, not `Form`.

I think you should try FBV(Function-Based View), not using form.

So I highly recommend to follow Django tutorials - it's very good - and take a step from basic request/response.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) is official Django documentation. It's easy to follow and well-organized.

I also recommend [Django girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/). It supports many languages and is good for beginners.

Comment: It's an abbreviation of "Function-Based View". (https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/03/21/class-based-views-vs-function-based-views.html)